# Stop redirect to root when accessing location block for a folder outside server root in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I am running a web client for a mapping service and the app resides in a folder called prod. I have copied `prod` to `var/www/html/`.

This is my `sites-enabled conf` for a Laravel app I have running already. I have added a location block for the prod folder at the end of the file. However when I go to `121.123.124.124/prod` it redirects to `121.123.124.124/login.`

How can I stop the redirect and make the server serve the mapping service `prod` folder instead?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 121.123.124.124;
    
    root /var/www/html/laravel-app/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    location ^~ /qgisserver {
        gzip           off;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/qgisserver.socket;
    }

    location ^~ /prod {
          root /var/www/html/prod
          index index.html
    }


}
```

Comment: If the files are in `/var/www/html/prod`, you should use `root /var/www/html;` - And two lines in you configuration are missing terminating `;`s.

Comment: @RichardSmith thank you changing root to `/var/www/html;` solves it. Yes thank you for picking that up I have added the `;` s.